# google facets not give me accurate count .so How can improve accuracy of facet count?

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

We are use google search indexes and facets to count numbers of unique values in facet entities . But the count that the facet entities return is not accurate .i following this document for build search index
   [faceted_search](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/search/faceted_search)

How can improve accuracy of search results?

Comment: I don't think there is any straightforward way to improve the accuracy of the Search results. In fact, the Faceted search should return the correct results if implemented appropriately.  Ensure that your queries follow the conjunctive normal form, refer to this [link](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/72428311#comment5). The behavior might be specific to your data, your queries and implementation.

Comment: Perhaps you can share a query that doesn't work well, the search result received and the expected values. It should contain information on how many documents were found for that query and where the [cursor](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/search/cursorclass) is currently set.